# fread to EOF? limit

Tags: php

I have the following lines;

```
$buff = fread($this->socketMaster, 10240);
```

&&

```
$buff[] = $this->decodeFromServer(fread($this->socketMaster, 10240));
```

I have problem that these two lines are cutting off long responses; I tried increasing it to like `1024000` however there is limit and still doesn't change and cuts off the responses. I looked at the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) about fread and saw maybe its possible to read to EOF? How would I alter the two code examples above to read to End of file.

Thank for any help. It would be great to have no limit at all.

Comment: Does `file_get_contents()` work?

Comment: Just look at the first example in the documentation you linked: `$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));`

Comment: @NigelRen file_get_contents does not work.

Comment: or try `stream_get_contents()`

Comment: this is also not a file with a file path but a response from a web socket server.

Comment: @CornelRaiu let me give it a try

Comment: if not, you may try to use socket_get_meta_data function to ge the number of the bytes coming through

Comment: @CornelRaiu I get endless loading, doesn't seem to load the page.